# How to use OneDrive for audio file storage instead of Azure Blob for Batch Speech Transcription?

Tags: speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, transcription

I want to use Azure Cognitive Service Speech [Batch Transcription APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/batch-transcription) with OneDrive instead of using an Azure blob storage location. Is this possible? Any workarounds that can help me achieve the same? Can I create a stream and pass that instead?

I already have the git hub [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples/batch/csharp) for batch processing working but changing it to a location other than Azure Storage gives an error "The recordings URI contains invalid data."

I am trying to change RecordingsBlobUri in [Program.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/batch/csharp/program.cs) in the sample where I want to provide a OneDrive url instead of Azure Blob

```
        // recordings and locale
        private const string Locale = "en-US";
        private const string RecordingsBlobUri = "<SAS URI pointing to an audio file stored in Azure Blob Storage>";
```

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/batch-transcription?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#storage):

> Batch transcription supports Azure Blob storage for reading audio and
> writing transcriptions to storage.

There is no possibility to use OneDrive to provide the audio file that you want to process.